# Microsoft Sculpt Ergonomic Keyboard Backspace Key Not Working

Tags: windows-7, wireless-keyboard

Just purchased sculpt ergonomic keyboard for use with Windows 7 64 bit. Three days in the backspace key stopped working as a basic backspace command. Strangely, the windows key + bckspace DOES work.

Any help would be appreciated as I love the keyboard but need my backspace working!

Comment: Does the keyboard work on another computer?

Comment: Just checked - no.

Comment: The keyboard is faulty.  Return it.

Comment: Just had the same thing happen with mine - is a couple months old - but Windows key + backspace is not working for me - did you resolve this? For me it works for about 3 presses after replugging the wireless USB dongle and then stops again.

Answer (score 5):

Symptoms: Backspace key does not work until you reconnect the dongle. Then a lot of backspaces happen at once.

Solution: In my case, I had my numberpad sitting under some heavy paper that was pushing on the Backspace key continuously. The software must have been filtering out subsequent Backspace commands because of this. The rest of the keyboard still worked.

After removing my numberpad from under the paper, my regular Backspace key is working again.